# How can I remove child from Firebase database using a delele button?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

By using  the following code I read the all child value from firebase database and display all value in a div and every div have a delete button But if want to delete a particular child by click delete button(using loaddelete function) it delete the 1st child of the database . Please can someone tell me how can I remove a particular child by using delete button? Thanks in advance

```js
   <script>//from db
        var Ref = firebase.database().ref('Driver');

        Ref.on("child_added", function(snap) {
        document.querySelector('.main-content').innerHTML += contactHtmlFromObject(snap.val());
        });

function contactHtmlFromObject(Driver){
  console.log(Driver);
  var html = '';
    html +='<div class="col-md-4">';
    html +='    <div class="bg-primary img_details">';
    html +='            <div class="row">';
    html +='                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4                              img-wrapper" style="height:200px;">';
    html +='                    <div class="only-img">';
    html +='                    <img src="'+Driver.FilePhoto+'"                                 height="100%" width="100%">';
    html +='                    </div>';
    html +='                    <div class="only-option">';
    html +='                         <div class="row">';
    html +='                            <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                                <input                                                      type="checkbox"> Disabled';
    html +='                            </div>';
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="row">';
    html +='                            <div class="col-md-4 col-                                 sm-4 col-xs-4">';
    html +='                                <div type="button"                                              class="btn btn-primary                              edit" onclick="loadedit()"                                      >Edit</div>';
    html +='                            </div>';
    html +='                            <div class="col-md-6 col-                         sm-6 col-xs-6">';
    html +='                                <div type="button"                            class="btn btn-primary delete"                                    onclick="loaddelete()" >Delete</div>';
    html +='                          </div>';
    html +='                         </div>';
    html +='                    </div>';
    html +='                </div>';
    html +='                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8                              details-wrapper">';
    html +='                    <div class="row">';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>Name:</b>                                              '+Driver.Fname+' '+Driver.Lname;
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>Address:</b>                                       '+Driver.Address;
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>Experience:</b>                                          '+Driver.Experience+' Years';
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>Phone Number:</b>                          '+'<span id="phoneid">'+Driver.Phone+"</span>";
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>Gender:</b>                                  '+Driver.Gender;
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>Date of Birth:</b>                                 '+Driver.DOB;
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                            <b>PIN:</b>                                   '+Driver.Pin+'</span';
    html +='                        </div>';
    html +='                        <div class="col-md-12">';
    html +='                        <b>Hired Date:</b>                                        '+Driver.HireDate;
    html +='                     </div>';
    html +='                  </div>';
    html +='               </div>';
    html +='            </div>';
    html +='        </div>';
    html +='        </div>';
    return html;
}

function loaddelete(e) {
    var fdb = firebase.database().ref();
    var phoneid=document.getElementById('phoneid').innerText;
      if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
         alert(fdb.child("Driver/id"+phoneid+'/'));
          
      }
    window.location="driver.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a node from Firebase, you must know its entire path. Right now your code knows only `/Driver` and then just finds the first element with `id=phoneid` and creates `/Driver/first_phone_id_value` out of it.

To delete the driver that the user clicked, you need to make sure that:

1. each driver in the HTML also contains the key of that driver
2. detect the key of the driver the user clicked on, and pass that to your JavaScript code
3. delete the driver for that specific key

So the first step is to get the key for each driver into the HTML that you generate. The key is available in `Snapshot.key`, which you're currently not using. So let's first pass the key to your HTML generator, in addition to the value:

```
Ref.on("child_added", function(snap) {

    document.querySelector('.main-content').innerHTML += contactHtmlFromObject(snap.key, snap.val());
});
```

Now in `contactHtmlFromObject`, we pass the key into the HTML into the call to `loaddelete`:

```
function contactHtmlFromObject(Key, Driver){
  ...
  html +='<div type="button" class="btn btn-primary delete"                                    onclick="loaddelete('+Key+')" >Delete</div>';
```

And then finally in `loaddelete` we can use the key to create a reference to the driver that was clicked:

```
function loaddelete(key) {
  var fdb = firebase.database().ref();
  if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
    firebase.database().ref('Driver/'+key+'/') // create a reference to the driver
      .remove()                                // remove the driver
      .then(function() {                       // once the driver is removed
        window.location="driver.html";         // navigate to the driver page
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yaa I got it . I was forgot to pass the key But Now on clicking delete button display some error like this `driver.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: id0000000012 is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (driver.html:1)
onclick @ driver.html:1`        what should I do?